# How to add Minecraft client mods to Spout / Spoutcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

[Spout](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/spout/) is a bukkit plugin that allows some nice interaction with the modified client [Spoutcraft](http://dev.bukkit.org/client-mods/spoutcraft/), for example using server-side defined texture packs and which mods the client will use. This does include a feature to prevent players from cheating by installing client mods the usual way, since Spoutcraft checks for modifications of `minecraft.jar`.

Now since the *server* determines via Spout which mods the client uses, how can I set it up to provide normal client mods like [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-11-12w07b-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-feb-17/), [Rei's Minimap](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482147-11100-jan14-reis-minimap-v30-01/) or the client-side part of [IndustrialCraft²](http://www.industrial-craft.net/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't what Spout does, unfortunately. Spout adds an API for Bukkit plugins to control some aspects of the client. It does not add any support for additional client mods automatically. Some Bukkit plugins support Spout to add additional GUI elements, but that's all it does.

In theory, doing what you want could be possible, but you'd need someone to port your client mods to Bukkit plugins using Spout. Until then, you can't do that.

Comment: Pity, I see :-/ But why would the plugins need to be ported? Basically Spoutcraft would "just" need to be adjusted to load client mods à la Modloader but from the server instead of a local mods directory

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, that's true, but I don't believe that kind of support is coming in the near future, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Jake King's answer is not quite correct.

Spoutcraft uses a copy and paste method to get `minecraft.jar` in its `bin` folder. It copies from wherever you have `minecraft.jar` on your PC, makes sure it's the same as the one on minecraft.net, and uses it like that. This allows it to check that a `minecraft.jar` is vanilla without breaking the ToS and distributing `minecraft.jar`. If you don't have a vanilla and up-to-date `minecraft.jar`, then the Spoutcraft client won't work.

What I think should happen is: delete everything that solar connects to Spoutcraft. Download it again, but make sure your computer doesn't enter sleep mode to ensure the download completes uninterrupted. Use two different port applications and port forward a modified Spoutcraft with your mod in it to yourself. (If you don't know how to do that look it up.)

Then, replace it in your applications folder or jar file. next go get you mod put in the addons folder in Spoutcraft and go to `bin\minecraft.jar`. Turn it into a folder with `minecraft.jar` as the folder name, then drag and drop to replace the mod into minecraft.jar folder and the mod should work properly.

To recap: what just happened is that since you port forwarded the same application, it automatically sets the default, making it seem like the it's the default app and "unmodified," giving permission to use it from Spoutcraft's code. Since the `spoutcraft.jar` file has the mod installed, making the reference look exactly like the `minecraft.jar` with the mod installed, it will pass the check and let you play. The only downside is that if you want another mod, you will have to do this all over again, but including the other mod this time.

Comment: This needs more punctuation and grammar to be comprehensible.

Comment: I edited for grammar, but frankly, I don't understand what this answer is saying half the time.